# php - regexp match string and digit

Tags: php

I want to match this

```
{format i=34 ds=11 k=a /}

$patern = "/\{format[a-z0-9=\s]?\/\}/i";
```

but result is null

In additional question:

```
string string {format mat=34/} string string string string string string string string 

string string {format mat=34/} string string string string string string string string
```

1. $pattern = "/{format[a-z0-9=\s]*\/}/i";

   str_replace($pattern, 'test', $strings);

   it will replace all formats in string, i want to replace only first "format", and remove all another "format". How ?
2. when get match result is "{format mat=34/}". i want to find string begin with "mat=".

So i have this

```
$string = "{format mat=34/}";
$pattern = "/^mat=[0-9]*/"; // result is null
$pattern = "/mat=[0-9]*/"; // ok, but also effect with "{format wrongformat=34/}"
```

How to match string that begin with "mat="

Comment: Because you forgot about a quantifier for your character set. Just replace `?` with `*`

Comment: in pattern i have "\s", it not match space ?

Comment: it does ;-) I deleted my that comment after few seconds after I posted it ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match something multiple times, use `*`. `?` just matches up to one count:

```
"/\{format[a-z0-9=\s]*\/\}/i"
```